# When is controller other than Zend_Controller_Request_Http

Tags: php, zend-framework

I keep seeing this line of code in many plugins. What exactly does it do, and what other possibilities are there other than Request_Http

```
if (!$request instanceof Zend_Controller_Request_Http)
    return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that originally all of ZF's routing was based on the REQUEST_URI, so many of the routing classes operated on $request which was a string. In order to facilitate things such as routing for subdomains this was changed so that the whole request object was passed in. So checks such as the one in your example are merely checking that $request is a request object (and not a string) before calling its methods.

(Disclaimer: this is speculation based on my knowledge of ZF's routing classes, I may be wrong!)

Answer (score 1):

Sifting through the Zend Framework docs, I see that a sibling class of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` is `Zend_Controller_Request_Simple`, which is used to get information about command-line requests to a ZF application. The plugins in question probably only work for web apps requested using a browser (or whatever HTTP client), so these plugins back out otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Even it is unusual every class, that extends [Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract.html) can occur.